# How to find element xpath if they have no any attribute values?

Tags: xpath

For an example

```
<tr><th>sample1</th><th>sample2</th></tr><tr<td>data1</td><td>data2</td></tr>
```

In this above table we have no any attribute values. But they only have TagName. From that how we can find the unique xpath for all of them.I try using xpath like

```
//tr[not(@class) and not (@id)]
```

But by using it they can fetch all tr .so from that how we can find the unique xpath. Please can anybody know the answer update immediately with some demo...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Why is the question tagged java ?

Comment: If you want nodes that have no attributes, try `//tr[not(@*)]`

Answer (score 0):

**Attribute values are handy but not required to select data in XPath.**

For example, for your XML, formatted for legibility and fixed to be well-formed,

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>sample1</th>
    <th>sample2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data1</td>
    <td>data2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

each of the following XPath expressions,

- **via position:** `/table/tr[2]/td[2]`
- **via content:** `//td[.='data2']`
- **via adjacency:** `//td[.='data1']/following-sibling::td[1]`
- **via heading:** `//tr[2]/td[count(../../tr/th[.='sample2']/preceding-sibling::th)+1]`

would select

```
    <td>data2</td>
```

without relying upon attribute values.

**See also**

- [How to select table entry via XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30354338/290085)