# XPath for HTML table element using headers

Tags: html, xml, xpath, html-table

I have a simple table like this one:

```
          <table>
              <tbody><tr>
                <th> Name1 </th>
                <td>
                  A
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Name2</th>
                <td>
                  B
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody></table>
```

I need the XPath to the value B, which I can do with:

```
//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]
```

However this relies on the position of the row (the number 2), which may change from one example to another. I would like to get the XPath of element B but using the header name (Name2) instead of the position.

Any idea of how to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//th[normalize-space()='Name2']/following-sibling::td
```

well select the first `td` element following each `th` element whose normalized string value is `'Name2'`.  (By testing the normalized string value of `td`, any leading and trailing whitespace will be ignored.  `contains()` has the problem that it will also match, for example, `'Name20'`.)

### See also

- [How to select table entry via XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30354338/290085)